# Google Earth Engine - counts days of the longest dry period in a time period

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth

I'm trying to map the max number of consecutive days with rain <1 mm in Google Earth Engine.

This is the link to the full code in GEE, you can see and run it

https://code.earthengine.google.com/22b5c20d2700a2ffb5989f892838ac58

This is the portion of the code that calculates the longest dryperiod in a x time period

```
// dry period calculation
function drylength(current, previous){
  previous = ee.List(previous);  // cast to establish the client-side type
  var mask = current.remap([0], [1], 0,"precipitation").rename('drydays');
  var sum = mask.add(previous.get(-1)).multiply(mask);

  return previous.add(sum);
}

var list = ee.List(dataset.iterate(drylength, ee.List([
  dataset.max()
    .remap([0], [0], 0, "precipitation")
    .rename('precipitation')
])));
var dryperiod = list.get(-1);
```

When I run the code for counting the number of days of the longest dry period, the code returns the right number only if the dry period reach the end of the selected time period test.

For instance if I am looking for the longest dry period in 4 days timestep i get the following:

rain days 1 2 3 4
          0,0,1,1 = 0 dry days (expecting 2)
          0,1,0,0 = 2 dry days (OK)
legend:
0 = no rain days 
1 = rainy days

How can I solve this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.